# How to get a jquery error div to fade out when all errors are cleared

Tags: jquery

I've got some code that I've been using to show all my form errors at the top of a form for a change.  The code fades in the error box but when all the errors have been cleared it just snaps shut.  I would prefer to either have it fade away or slide up so the transition isn't so jarring but I can't figure out how to accomplish this and would appreciate a helping hand.  Below is the code I'm using to create the error block.  Thanks much in advance.

```
            errorElement: "div",
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            offset = element.offset();
            error.addClass('message');  // add a class to the wrapper
            error.css('position', 'absolute');
            error.css('left', offset.left + element.outerWidth());
            error.hide().insertBefore(element)
        },
        onfocusin: function( element, event ) {
            this.lastActive = element;

           // hide error label and remove error class on focus if enabled
            if ( this.settings.focusCleanup && !this.blockFocusCleanup ) {
                if ( this.settings.unhighlight ) {
                    this.settings.unhighlight.call( this, element, this.settings.errorClass, this.settings.validClass );
                }
                this.addWrapper(this.errorsFor(element)).fadeOut();
            }
        },
        showErrors: function() {
            var i, elements;
            for ( i = 0; this.errorList[i]; i++ ) {
                var error = this.errorList[i];
                if ( this.settings.highlight ) {
                    this.settings.highlight.call( this, error.element, this.settings.errorClass, this.settings.validClass );
                }
                this.showLabel( error.element, error.message );
            }
            if ( this.errorList.length ) {
                this.toShow = this.toShow.add( this.containers );
            }
            if ( this.settings.success ) {
                for ( i = 0; this.successList[i]; i++ ) {
                    this.showLabel( this.successList[i] );
                }
            }
            if ( this.settings.unhighlight ) {
                for ( i = 0, elements = this.validElements(); elements[i]; i++ ) {
                    this.settings.unhighlight.call( this, elements[i], this.settings.errorClass, this.settings.validClass );
                }
            }
            this.toHide = this.toHide.not( this.toShow );
            this.hideErrors();
            this.addWrapper( this.toShow ).fadeIn();
        },

        highlight: function(element) {
            $(element).prev('label').addClass("error");
            $(element).addClass("error");
        },
        unhighlight: function(element) {
            $(element).prev('label').removeClass("error");
            $(element).addClass("valid");
        },
        errorContainer: $('#errorContainer'),
        errorLabelContainer: $('#errorContainer ul'),
        wrapper: 'li',
```

Comment: Have you tried .fadeOut() instead of .hide()?   http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Comment: I tried everywhere I could think of but nothing works so far. Will keep looking though.  Thanks.

Comment: I get a good feel for what is going on with the code here.  Can you create a jsfiddle for it?

Comment: Sorry - took a bit to get this together. Basically after you clear the errors, the container simply snaps shut - would like for it to fade out - instead.https://jsfiddle.net/43rdworld/f491w810/37/